# didSelectRowAt changing values in all rows

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

i don't know how does it happens that didSelectRowAt method changes all elements in array(at every index) 
print statements are there to visualise result and so after clicking cell 1 two times i got :
1
true true true
1
false false false

no idea how indexPath.row just went wild and go for whole range of my array
any help would be appreciated

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = itemArray[indexPath.row].title

    if itemArray[indexPath.row].done == true {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }else{
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }

    return cell
}

//MARK: TableView Delegate methods

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print(indexPath.row)
    if itemArray[indexPath.row].done == true {
        itemArray[indexPath.row].done = false

        print(itemArray[indexPath.row].done, itemArray[indexPath.row-1].done, itemArray[indexPath.row+1].done)

    }else{
        itemArray[indexPath.row].done = true
        print(itemArray[indexPath.row].done, itemArray[indexPath.row-1].done, itemArray[indexPath.row+1].done)
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

Item type is :

```
class Item {
    var title : String = ""
    var done : Bool = false
}
```

here's how array got populated:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let newItem: Item = Item()
    newItem.title = "asdaS"
    itemArray.append(newItem)
    itemArray.append(newItem)
    itemArray.append(newItem)

}
```

Comment: How are you adding items in `itemArray`? And what is the type of said item? Can you share that code?

Comment: for now it's just hard coded array with custom type item :

class Item {
    var title : String = ""
    var done : Bool = false
}

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. Instead, update the question and add the relevant code where you are populating the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only creating one object and appending the same object in the array. When you change any index, it updates the whole array because all the indices contain the some object

```
class Item {
    var name = ""
    var done = true
}

let x = Item()
var arr = [Item]()
for _ in 0..<5 {
    arr.append(x)
}

print(arr.flatMap({ $0.done })) //[true, true, true, true, true]
arr[1].done = false
print(arr.flatMap({ $0.done })) //[false, false, false, false, false]
```

What you need to do is create a separate object for each index

```
class Item {
    var name = ""
    var done = true
}

var arr = [Item]()
for _ in 0..<5 {
    let x = Item() //NOTICE THAT THIS LINE HAS BEEN MOVED INSIDE THE LOOP
    arr.append(x)
}

print(arr.flatMap({ $0.done })) //[true, true, true, true, true]
arr[1].done = false
print(arr.flatMap({ $0.done })) //[true, false, true, true, true]
```

Comment: thanks, ye it seem i got just array of one element that is more than 1 time in different rows, so my indexPath.row ain't gain wild

Comment: No worries. Cheers